# How to submit data in CLDR

Tags: unicode, cldr

My name is Nahid Hossain. A Software Engineer from Bangladesh. We want to develop CLDR of Bengali language for Bangladesh. We are facing difficulties to figure how to submit our CLDR of Bengali language for Bangladesh. As far as I understand , I need a account to do so.

1.How to open an CLDR account.
2. How to submit our data.
3. Is CLDR only limited to bug fixing?

Regards,
Nahid Hossain

Answer (score 1):

Nahid, http://cldr.unicode.org/index/survey-tool/accounts is the right page to learn how to contribute to CLDR.

- You can contribute entirely new data, or correct entries. The bug reporting form may be more appropriate if there is just a single fix needed.
- For contributing new locales, there is minimum data required:  which script is used, which characters are customary for writing the language, and some basic translations of the language's own name and related names.

Bengali is already available in CLDR, so you would not need to start from scratch there. I recommend requesting an account for Bengali and contributing to the process.